# Watin crawling c# click button submit the page ignoring the text box value entered

Tags: watin

Hello i am trying to click a search button via watin code

```csharp
IE ie = new IE();
ie.GoTo("http://www.apartments.com/");
ie.TextField(Find.ById("quickSearchLookup")).TypeText("5000");
Link link = ie.Link(Find.ByUrl("http://www.apartments.com/search/"));
link.Click();
```

i have also tried this

```csharp
ie.TextField(Find.ById("quickSearchLookup")).Focus();
ie.TextField(Find.ById("quickSearchLookup")).Value = "5000";
```

instead of type text

but when click it ignore the value i entered on the text box and get the default value 
here is the html source of the page

```html
<input type="text" id="quickSearchLookup" class="quickSearchLookup hasPrefilledValue" autocorrect="false" placeholder="Search by Location or Point of Interest">

and here is the click button
<a href="http://www.apartments.com/search/" class="go" title="Search apartments for rent"><span>Go</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

That website has code so every time you focus on the page it will clear the textbox and start from scratch. If you are running a program and switch back and forth the search box will be cleared so try to avoid doing that (SHIFT+TAB to set focus on IE-Chrome, etc).

The following code does what you need, just let it run and after it finishes go back to your browser (or better yet, if you have more than one monitor set a breakpoint at the top of the code so as soon as your browser opens move it to a second monitor and you will be able to see everything happening while you step through).

```
    using (IE ie = new IE())
    {
        ie.GoTo("http://www.apartments.com/");
        ie.ShowWindow(WatiN.Core.Native.Windows.NativeMethods.WindowShowStyle.ShowMaximized);
        ie.WaitForComplete();
        ie.TextField(Find.ById("quickSearchLookup")).TypeText("5000");
        var go = ie.Link(Find.ByClass("go"));
        if (go.Exists)
        {
            go.Click();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.